# is it possible to get the public facebook wall feeds when not logged in?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall, auth-token

I'm accually asking is it possible to get public wall feeds without auth token?
If I'm not logged in to facebook, I can still see the public posts ,this is a good example : http://www.facebook.com/adele
I'm using facebook graph API like this:

```
uri ="https://graph.facebook.com/" + this.getString(R.string.wall_id) + "/feed?access_token="+Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken();

JSONObject json = GetJSON.fromURL(uri);
```

If I'm connected to FB I'm successfully get the feeds. Do I need to ask for a new token when I'm offline?

thanx!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can go to:
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[APP_ID]&format=json
For example: Nike Facebook page - http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=15087023444&format=json

To find out the APP_ID for a page go to https://graph.facebook.com/[page_name] and in the output you will find it.
e.g.: https://graph.facebook.com/nike - "id": "15087023444"

More info here: http://costimuraru.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/facebook-how-to-find-out-a-fan-page-id/

Comment: How exactly this related to the question?

Comment: @JuicyScripter - they correctly described a way to get the wall posts from a public page without an access token using the page feed.

Comment: @Adam, users are not pages and it'll be just wrong to assume this will work for users, because it don't!

Comment: @Adam, just re-read the post and I should apologize for wrongly interpreting it.

Comment: @Adam. I've incorrectly assumed the question is about users walls and not about pages. I've corrected my answer to provide info about that case as well. Note that this solution will work for pages only (it's not exactly stated in question nor tags that this is about pages or users)

Comment: @JuicyScripter To answer your question, I assumed from the example provided (http://www.facebook.com/adele) that the question was about Facebook pages. You are right, it might not work for users, but that was not what I had in mind.

Comment: ... and have your tried the uri's posted above? both should give you the wall posts in json (if wall posts in the specific wall is publicly visible)

Comment: @CostiMuraru Salut Costi! One question, how far will this take me? Can I get the user wall photos for example? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

To access `feed` connection of `user` you need `read_stream` permission which automatically means it can't be accessed by unauthorized users.

You can however access `posts` connection of `user` using **any valid `access_token`** which includes only user's own posts. Accessing it with `access_token` other than one for owning user will return only public posts.

You may use application `access_token` to access it for unauthorized users.

For pages `feed` connection may be accessed the same way, using **any valid `access_token`**

**BTW**, application `access_token` may be either in ["new format"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications) or old `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need an access token, even if the posts are public and you can view the page publicly even if not logged into Facebook.

Most companies do this because if people starting mis using the API they can block people based on the token.

However I want to point out that @Costi Muraru is correct in that you can gather the posts of the page via the feed using the URL they mentioned in their post.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Costi Muraru on his beautifull posted link :http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=15087023444&format=json
I thank you for that amigo.

I have found an alternative, I use the following :

```
uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" + wall_id + "&type=post";
```

Hope this helps anyone

Comment: Is that wall_id the same as the page's id?

I'm trying to use the graph API to get a page's public posts without access token.

Comment: use the Graph API Explorer : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola     make some tests, see if its a wall id or page id. not everybody has page. page is the public face of users in fb

Comment: I was trying to get a page's public posts. I've tried to use a page id and the search returned an empty data array.

Comment: If this page set up as a FB Fan Page than you must "Like" him. go ahead and try this and reply with results.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to "Like" that page since I need the request to be anonymous.
Like the question titles says "when not logged in".
What I would like was to get all the posts from a page without providing an access token, that is, a not authenticated request.