# How to get Facebook Page News Feed including Likes and Comments without user login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get news feed from my Facebook page and display it in my app including the likes and comments on the posts in the Facebook page news feed without requiring user login. I'm new in Facebook API/SDK. Is this possible? I already found these links, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964359/is-it-possible-to-get-the-public-facebook-wall-feeds-when-not-logged-in) and [here](http://costimuraru.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/facebook-how-to-find-out-a-fan-page-id/)

But using the link:

> https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[Page ID]&format=json

It only returns JSON containing posts from my Facebook page without the likes and comments from the posts.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Get a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

Comment: I don't want to login as a page or even login. I just need to display the News Feeds on my Facebook page. I'd like to get results in JSON format but I'm using this for my iOS app.